# How to remove wonderplugin.com link from WonderPlugin slider

Tags: wordpress, slider

I am relatively new to the WordPress. I am using free version of the WonderPlugin slider in my site. There is a link coming in the top left corner of the slider showing wonderplugin.com.

Is it possible to remove that link from the free version of the WonderPlugin.

I am using WordPress 4.0 and WonderPlugin Slider Free Version 2.6

Comment: You might want to consider that the WonderPlugin people make software you find useful -- it's courteous to allow their link to show, or to pay them a little money for the full version!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all if you want to use free version of the WondePlugin, you should be fine to show the wonderplugin link on the slider. You can avoid that link by using commercial version of plugin.

As far as free version is concern, the link can be removed by the custom css.

On the edit slider screen of the plugin click on **Option** tab.

Click on **Advance Option** and put following css in the **Custom CSS** box.

```
div.amazingslider-box-1 :nth-child(3) { 
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

This will hide the link.

Answer (score 3):

CSS

```
.wonderpluginslider-container{
    display: none
}
```

JS

```
jQuery('.wonderpluginslider-container')
    .show()
    .find('a[href="http://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-slider/"]')
    .parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers but it doesn't work with the WonderPlugin Grid Gallery Free Version 2.2., which I was looking for when I stumpled over the thread. To remove the watermark from the grid gallery, go to wonderplugin-carousel/engine/wonderplugingridgallery.js and look for

```
<div style="display:none;position:absolute;top:4px;left:4px;padding:2px
```

Change the display:block to display:none and the watermark is no longer visible.

Answer (score 2):

You have to search for:
`wpositioncssdefault:"display:block;position:absolute;bottom:8px;right:8px;` line 162
in the wonderplugincarousel.js and then you change `display:block;` to `display:none;`. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**wonderplugincarousel.js**

Line No.259 replace `display:block` with `display:none`,
change `visibility:visible` to `visibility:hidden`
and remove `!important`
and change `mklink.css("visibility")=="visible"` to `mklink.css("visibility")==""`

Answer (score 1):

Open `engine\wonderplugingallery.js` and search for `var commonOptions`. Then change

```
var commonOptions = {
    /* other options */
    ...
    fv: true,
    ...
}
```

**to**

```
var commonOptions = {
    /* other options */
    ...
    fv: false,
    ...
}
```

and the plugin will take care rest(no custom CSS and JS headache).

I have checked it with **Version 8.6** and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

These solutions are all updated and solved by WonderPlugin admins. But here is the new solution for WonderPlugin Portfolio Grid Gallery (Version 11.8):

open:  engine\wonderplugingridlightbox.js

on line 66 :
`title='WordPress Gallery'><div style='display:block;width:180px;height:20px;text-align:center;border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px`

Change `display:block` to `display:none`

And here we go!

Answer (score 0):

Open your style.css and then put the code below

```
div.html5gallery-container-0
div.html5gallery-box-0
div.html5gallery-elem-0
div.html5gallery-elem-img-0
a{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You have to search for: wpositioncssdefault:"display:block;position:absolute;bottom:8px;right:8px; line 162 in the wonderplugincarousel.js and then you change display:block; to display:none;.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution

```
div.amazingcarousel-image :nth-child(3) { visibility: hidden;}
```

because free version link is the 3rd child div in parent div with class- amazingcarousel-image

Answer (score 0):

search for `this.options.watermarktext=this.options.vermk;` and replace `this.options.vermk` with `nil`

Answer (score 0):

Good way to purchase the plugin and it is removed automatically but in free version you can add the following css to make it invisible.

```
div.amazingslider-box-1 div:nth-child(3) { 
   visibility: hidden !important;
   width:0 !important;
   height: 0 !important;
   padding: 0 !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no style.css file. There are only wonderpluginslider.css and wonderpluginsliderengine.css
So do you know where the file and code?

Also i inspected that element on my internet browser and i saw this codes:

```
<div class="amazingslider-text-box-1" style="display: block;">

    <div class="amazingslider-text-wrapper-1" style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"></div>

</div>
<div style="display:block;position:absolute;top:6px;left:6px;font:12px A…or:#fff;opacity:0.9;filter:alpha(opacity=90);cursor:pointer;"

    <a target="_blank" title="Responsive jQuery Slider" style="text-decoration:none;font:12px Arial,Tahoma,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#333;" href="http://wonderplugin.com/wordpress-slider/">

        WordPress Slider Free Version
    </a>

</div>
```

"Wonder Plugin" (Free Wordpress Slider Plugin)