# How to remove wonderplugin.com link from free Wonder Plugin slider?

Tags: wordpress, slider

I am integrating Wonder Plugin Slider and I don’t have very much knowledge about wonder Plugin. How to remove watermark form top left corner.
I am using 4.2.3 WordPress and Wonder Plugin Slider Free Version 2.6
Do any one have any solution for the same, please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove wonderplugin.com link from WonderPlugin slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436352/how-to-remove-wonderplugin-com-link-from-wonderplugin-slider)

Answer (score 1):

I forget what the div class or id was but you basically have to go into a plugin file and edit it.

wonderplugin-slider -> engine -> wonderpluginslider.js

In that file, I believe you need to find 'wposcss' and change the `display:block !important;` to `display:none !important;`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code from wonderplugin-slider -> engine -> wonderpluginslider.js into word and search for 'wpocss' change it copy all and paste it into wonderplugin-slider -> engine -> wonderpluginslider.js

Answer (score 0):

wp-content -> plugins -> wonderplugin-slider -> engine -> wonderpluginslider.js

**just comment in line**

original code :

$(".amazingslider-box-" + this.id, this.container).append('' + html + "")

**Comment code :**

//$(".amazingslider-box-" + this.id, this.container).append('' + html + "")

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just write below line of code in css file. Hope this helps.

.amazingcarousel-item div.amazingcarousel-image :nth-child(3) { z-index:-99;}

Answer (score 0):

```
engine->wonderpluginslider.js (line 385)

mkdiv.attr({style:mkdiv.attr("style")+"display:block !important;visibility:visible !important;font-size:12px!important;"})}
```

change to

```
mkdiv.attr({style:mkdiv.attr("style")+"display:none !important;visibility:hidden !important;font-size:12px!important;"})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file `wonderplugin-slider/engine/wonderpluginslider.js`

And overwrite:

```
this.options.watermarktext= '';
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

OPEN "wonderplugincarousel.js" file from "wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-carousel/engine"

1. Search for the string "AMC".
2. Change the conditional operator != to ==

Answer (score 0):

Open the file

```
wonderplugin-slider/engine/wonderpluginslider.js
```

Search for

```
this.options.watermarktext=this.options.vermk
```

Change the above line to:

```
this.options.watermarktext= '';
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

Go to wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-carousel/engine/wonderplugincarousel.js

search "display:block!important;visibility:visible!important"

1. Change "display:block!important" to "display:none!important"
2. Change "visibility:visible!important" to "visibility:hidden!important"

You are watermark free!

I had the same problem and all the answers seemed to be from a previous version of the plugin, but this one works with version 12.7 which is the newest version as of 3/29/18

Answer (score 0):

for version 13.3:

Go to `wonderplugin-carousel/engine/wonderplugincarousel.js` and do below two steps

1. Search for this line

```
div style="display:block!important;visibility:visible!important;z-index:999;position:absolute;bottom:4px;right:4px;padding:3px;
```

Change the `display:block` to `display:none` and `visibility:visible` to `visibility:hidden`

2. Search for this line

```
this.options.watermarktext=this.options.fvm;
```

and change it to `this.options.watermarktext=' ';`

Answer (score 0):

open plugin folder wonderplugin-gridgallery > engine > wonderplugingridgallery.js edit this file.

go to the page and inspect the watermark it will show you inline-style > display:block !important ; visibility : visible !important ; position: absolute; top: 2px; left:2px etc and more

now just copy the display: block !important property from inspect element and search in wonderplugingridgallery.js file you will see all the css there you just have to change the display property to none > display: none !important;

that's it now you wont see any water mark